# How to get hash value from an asynchronous function?

Tags: javascript, cryptojs

I use CryptoJs to have hash (sha256) of a PDF file.

I already have the hash of my file but I can't get it outside the function.

This is my code :

```
var reader = new FileReader();
var hash = "";

reader.onloadend = function(evt) {
    if (evt.target.readyState == FileReader.DONE) { // DONE == 2
        var i8a = new Uint8Array(evt.target.result);
        var a = []; for (var i = 0; i < i8a.length; i += 4) { a.push(i8a[i] << 24 | i8a[i + 1] << 16 | i8a[i + 2] << 8 | i8a[i + 3]); }
        var wordArray = CryptoJS.lib.WordArray.create(a,i8a.length);
        var hash = CryptoJS.SHA256(wordArray);
        alert(hash);
    }
};

var blob = file.slice(0, file.size + 1);
reader.readAsArrayBuffer(blob);

alert(hash);
```

The first alert give me the sha, but the second is empty.
How can I do to get hash defined into the function to use it after?

if I add a callBack function it working. 
But I wanted to make an Ajax request, and when I add the request into a callBack function like this :

```
function callBack(hash){
     $.ajax({
          type: "POST",
          url:"http://...",
          dataType:'json',
          data:({shaPdf: hash}),
          success: function(data) {
             //...
           },
          error: function(error) {
           }
           });
```

I have this error into my console :

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'words' of undefined
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need a call back function:

```
var reader = new FileReader();
var hash = "";

reader.onloadend = function(evt) {
    if (evt.target.readyState == FileReader.DONE) { // DONE == 2
        var i8a = new Uint8Array(evt.target.result);
        var a = []; for (var i = 0; i < i8a.length; i += 4) { a.push(i8a[i] << 24 | i8a[i + 1] << 16 | i8a[i + 2] << 8 | i8a[i + 3]); }
        var wordArray = CryptoJS.lib.WordArray.create(a,i8a.length);
        var hash = CryptoJS.SHA256(wordArray);
        callBack(hash); // <-- callBack at the end of this function
    }
};

var blob = file.slice(0, file.size + 1);
reader.readAsArrayBuffer(blob);

function callBack(hash)
{
   alert(hash);
}
```

Since your `reader` is loading the file asynchronous, the second `alert` fires immediately after the other code. The `reader` is not done yet loading the file, so hash is empty. If we wrap the `alert` into a function, which we call upon after the `onloadend`, we are able to use the value outside of the function.

Comment: It's working, but after I wanted to make an ajax request, and your solution doesn't work if I add an ajax request into the callBack function. Have you got any idea?

Comment: It's basically the same. Read up on asynchronous calls. Ajax calls also need a call back after they are done.

Comment: Sorry I don't understand, how can I do a callback on ajax request?

Comment: I've update my code

Comment: I see now, you can put an ajax call into it, after that something in your code breaks it. I can't see it with this example. Please start another question, since this one has been answered. The problem you're facing now has a different origin.

Comment: I think I find the problem. the type of hash passed as parameter into callback function is an object not a string. I don't understant when I do an `alert` hash I have my PDF hash, but when I look into the oject hash I can't see anything witch can be a hash. Do you know how can I get the real hash value ?

Comment: It's okay I found the solution!